# $\mathbb{N} ^{\mathbb{N}} \equiv_c \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\mathbb{N} ^{\mathbb{N}}=\{f: \text{f is a function}, f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \}$

Is $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\equiv_c\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$?

Since $f$ is a function with no restrictions, i.e. not one-to-one or onto I can map each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ anywhere I like. If I now represent each mapping as a set, for example if $f$ is constant such that $f(x)=1, \forall x \in \mathbb{N}$, then I would represent this function by $\{1\}$. Similarly, I would represent the identity function by $\{1,2, \dots\}$. I think the set of all functions represented as above would result in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: You probably mean $|\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}| = |\mathcal P(\mathbb N)|$...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are proposing a mapping which maps a function $f$ to its image $f(\mathbb N)$. You are correct in assuming that this mapping will tell you something, however, it is obviously not bijective as it is not injective (can you see why?). It is, however, surjective (not difficult to prove), meaning that it tells you that $|\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}|\geq |\mathcal P(\mathbb N)|$.

Comment: I think it actually gives us the other direction. Unrelated, this also requires the use of choice, which should be unnecessary here.

Comment: @JonathanY. I agree.

Comment: I know $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\equiv_c \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \equiv_c \mathbb{R}$. Then wouldn't there also exists a surjection such that $ \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \ge_c \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$? And then, in this case, it is true that $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\equiv_c\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.